# value of a textarea element

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to use value of a textarea element, but I am not able to get it

```js
function postComment(element) {
  const content = element.previousSibling.value;
  console.log(content);
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="comment-editor">
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="" id="someid" rows="4"></textarea>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary my-2" onClick="postComment(this)">Comment</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

It gives `undefined` as output

Comment: That’s because you are looking at the white space text node _between_ those two elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling#Notes

Comment: can you tell what is the correct code for this

Comment: `element.closest('.form-group').querySelector('textarea').value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try the below code

```js
function postComment(element) {
  const content = element.parentNode.firstElementChild.value
  console.log(content);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="comment-editor">
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="" id="someid" rows="4"></textarea>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary my-2" onClick="return postComment(this)">Comment</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @SachinKumar **Note** this will always give you the first item insite the parent `div`. not the one before the button.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function postComment(element) {
  const content = element.previousElementSibling.value;
  console.log(content);
}
```

```html
<form action="" class="comment-editor">
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="" id="someid" rows="4"></textarea>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary my-2" onClick="postComment(this)">Comment</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Your problem is that you use `previousSibling` when it should be `previousElementSibling`.

Comment: Note that It will work only if textarea come as the previous element of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have an ID for the `<input>` field, i would have used the following instead:

```
function postComment() {
  const content = document.getElementByID("someid").value;
  console.log(content);
}
```

And no need for the parameter here:

```
onClick="postComment();"
```

Comment: my whole code does not allow me to do it this anyway, this is also correct

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch value by this modification in your code

```
const content = document.querySelector("#someid").value;
```